# How much disk space is required to install KVM hypervisor on a CentOS machine?

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, disk-space-utilization

I want to install KVM on my CentOS machine. But the main partition size of my CentOS is about 50GB with only 15GB available. My question is should i extend the main partition in order to install KVM ? if yes, how to extend the main partition size?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install KVM, QEMU, libvirt, virt-manager, your available space is more than enough. The absolute minimum is KVM and QEMU which take very little space.
If you want to install oVirt, a vSphere or MS SCVMM like web console, you can also proceed, but probably you'll soon need more space - it also needs a DB backend.

But you should be careful regarding the locations of VMs - virtual disks and ISOs, that's the ones taking space. Probably you'll have to change the default location of the libraries.

Comment: thx!!!!!!!!!!!!